# How can i add an entry to text field suggestions in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html, forms

A text input in Chrome can have auto suggestions by Chrome based on what the user entered previously. Example is in the Screenshot. In this example the suggestion "RunBatch..." was entered by me at some point in the past. However I do not know how it got saved. I am trying to add new entries, but it does not work. After entering the text I tried key combinations like ALT+Enter etc., but no luck.
How can i add a new text?
Also is there maybe a database file saving those which i could edit directly?

[image]

Comment: This is probably the browser's auto complete function. What research have you done regarding this?

Comment: Chrome only has autocomplete for addresses and payment